# What is the correct way of calling fp rand and randint?

Tags: expl3

All my attempts to use floating point functions `rand()`, and `randint(...,...)` for that matter, are failing. Using exactly the same syntax for other `fp` functions, for example `trunc()`, `sind()`, etc. produces the expected result. What am I missing with `rand()`?

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 8 April 2017
% BRIEF DESCRIPTION:
%  my code produces -ERROR: Unknown fp word rand-. What am I missing???
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \NewDocumentCommand\myRandomNumber{}
    {
      \fp_eval:n {rand()}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
  \myRandomNumber   
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `rand()` function has been added in December 2016, so you need a newer version of `xparse`. Your example runs for me without errors

Comment: The docs say `New: 2016-12-05`: can you add `\listfiles` and edit in the `File list` from the `.log`.

Comment: @Christian hupfer I am working with `MikTex 2.9`and the package manager shows the `L3kernel` with a `2016-11-22` time stamp. So far so good. Invoking `Miktex Update` I am informed that `L3kernel`, `L3experimental`, `L3packages` and a number of other packages I am using regularly are `obsolete` and ought to be `removed`, without any indication of what will replace them. This looks like the kind of `update` that could leave me sitting in a deep hole. What is your advice?

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth: Well, if you want to use the `rand` functions you need to update. Apparently you got aware of the new features anyway. You accepted David's answer which is telling you basically the same: 'up to date system' or 'xfp' package

Comment: @Christian hupfer All done, runs like clock-work. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code should make no error with an up to date system, but with an up to date system you can simplify it further using the new `xfp` package which exposes `\fp_eval:n` as a document level command `\fpeval`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand\myRandomNumber{\fpeval{rand()}}

%-----------------------
\begin{document}
  \myRandomNumber   
\end{document}
```